# Essential supremum and strictly positive measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and the essential supremum of $f$
$$e=\inf\{\alpha\ge 0 \mid |f|\le\alpha\text{ almost everywhere}\}$$

I can't see why $$\lambda^*\left(\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid |f(x)|\ge e-\epsilon\}\right)>0$$
for $a<b$ and $\epsilon>0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Could someone help me ?

**Fixed** after Didier Piau's comment.

Comment: The assertion is false. It is true if you replace $(a,b)$ by $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Or the statement should be: *There are* $a$ and $b$ such that $\ldots >0$.

Comment: @Didier Piau: Thank you, I fixed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $\alpha<e$ then $|f|$ is *not* less or equal $\alpha$ a.e. (else $\alpha\geq e$ by definition), so there is a set of positive measure where $|f|>\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the question, I should have taken a pause...